# JAVA HOME is set to 1.8 but eclipse uses java 9

Tags: java, eclipse

Maybe I understand something wrong, but I am confused.

When I run `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` I get:

```
9.0.4, x86_64:  "Java SE 9.0.4" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_161, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
```

But running `java -version` logs:

```
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

But in eclipse I get a lot of similar build errors. One of them is

```
(package javax.jws is declared in module java.xml.ws, which is not in the module graph)
```

Why is Eclipse using java 9 to compile the project? How can I set JAVA 8 to compile the project instead of Java 9?

I have set the java compiler to 1.8 in Eclipse but anyway I get a lot of module errors. Why?

[image]

Comment: What are you using to compile inside of eclipse?? Maven? or It is Eclipse who does the compile through its javac features??

Comment: You need to modify eclipse.ini file.

Comment: I am using unfortunately ant

Comment: I cannot see eclipse.ini file in the proj root folder

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project select build path -> configure build. In the opening window, there is JRE system library entry, edit it to point jdk8.